# Is it possible to search the table on all columns for word occurence, without repeating like operator?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to search for a word in occurrence in the table. In my table there are 80 columns available. Is there any possibilities are there to search for the a word without repeating the like operator for all the columns. I tried to figure this out in the net, but i cannot find the solution.
thanks in advance.

Comment: not really. You could concat all of the values in the columns into 1 value and run a 'like' against that, but that sounds like a bad idea. Do you really need to have 80 text columns that you search on with a 'like' statement? Performance might suffer

Comment: There are always ways around it, but for the sake of sanity let's say it's not possible. If it's a one time operation, just generate the query with a bit of code. If it's a common thing, create a fulltext index and search for that.

Comment: I've mentioned one way it can be done, but I cannot overstate how bad an idea this is. **You need to re-design your schema**.

Answer (score 4):

This almost certainly means you have major design problems in your schema and need to look at further normalization.

If it makes sense to search for a value over 80 columns... well, yeah, re-think your schema.

In *theory* you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM the_table
WHERE the_table::text LIKE '%word%';
```

which converts the whole tuple to its text form and then searches it. This is in practice a *terrible* idea, though; it'll include *all* columns, not just the text columns you want, it'll add quotes and other formatting for the row literal, and it won't tell you which column(s) the word appeared in.

The saner approach would usually be to use [in-database full-text search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html), which supports multi-column searches. Over 80 columns that's going to be awkward because you *do* have to repeat all the columns, but it's the *only* sane way to proceed. If it's too much hassle, you probably need to fix your schema design.

Comment: Actually I did a full text search in my app, I need to test it in the sql level too. Thats the reaso I've asked this question, Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Arun Re-phrased answer to indicate that I'm referring to in-database full-text search.

Comment: @Arun Glad to help. Please, though, look into [normalizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your schema, as it's highly likely that you really need to be storing all those columns in a secondary table. Also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Sure I do. In my app we're integrating other system and so we need to replicate some of their schema over here. The above schema is a replicated one. Thanks for your valuable guidance.

Answer (score -2):

Try this,

Below query based on Columnwise.

```
select COUNT(*) from dbo.TableNAme
where PatIndex('searchword',ColumnName) > 0
```

Comment: [tag:SQL] does not mean "Microsoft SQL Server". It means "the [Structured Query Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL)", the *interface* that is a *standard* for all databases (or kind-of, anyway). This question clearly refers to PostgreSQL, albeit only in the tags, not [tag:mssql] or [tag:sql-server]. Just because Microsoft chose an awful name for their product doesn't mean you have to go along with it ;-) . Downvoted not because of that, but because it also doesn't answer the question of how to search across many columns.